# Abel sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I recently proved that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to some value $S$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nr^n$ is Abel summable to $S$.

My problem is probably more elementary, as I'm quite new to analysis and have always had a bit of a tough time with power series. I can't seem to find a way to make this sum converge, so I'm not sure how to apply what I proved about Abel summability. I also have the definition of Abel summability:

> $$ \text{If} \lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nr^n = S \text{, then the series} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \text{ is Abel summable to } S.$$

I just can't reconcile this definition or the results of my recent proof with this particular series. Changing the sum to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n$ doesn't really improve the situation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That is an example of a divergent series that is Abel-summable. Look at the derivative of $\frac{1}{1+r}$.

Comment: The theorem you proved tells that $$\biggl[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\text{ is ordinary summable to }S\biggr]\quad\Rightarrow\quad\biggl[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\text{ is Abel summable to }S\biggr].$$ Now the example you are looking at tells that the converse is false. Indeed, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+1)\cdot r^n=\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}-1$$ for $|r|<1$ will show that your sum is Abel summable, and you may easily figure out its value. On the other hand, this sum diverges in ordinary summability.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh, okay, I get it! Seeing that the converse is false definitely makes sense. Thanks!